# Bulk File Rename

Tags: bash, shell, sh, sed, zsh

A function that funnels all filenames into a file and opens that file in vim. The user then changes the names, saves, and quits. Finally the function renames the files in the folder with the new names provided in the file.

```
bulkrename() {
    mkdir -p ~/.temp
    ls > ~/.temp/newfilenames && nvim ~/.temp/newfilenames
    local files=(*)
    for filenum in $(seq 1 $(ls | wc -l)); do
        mv ${files[${filenum}]} $(sed "${filenum}q;d" ~/.temp/newfilenames)
    done
    rm ~/.temp/newfilenames
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Always double-quote variables used in command arguments

The arguments of `mv` should have been double-quoted, like this:

```
mv "${files[${filenum}]}" "$(sed "${filenum}q;d" ~/.temp/newfilenames)"
```

#### The script is fragile

As it is, the script looks very fragile:

- The list of files for editing is generated by `ls`, and then the edited list items are paired up with the `files` array generated with `*`. I'm not sure the ordering is guaranteed to be consistent, and I think it would be painful to track down in the documentation if this is indeed the case. It would be easier to generate both lists in a way to ensure consistent ordering.
- Using `ls` to generate the list is problematic. The output of `ls > ...` will depend on active aliases. `command ls > ...` would be safer.
- Files whose names don't change will raise errors when executing `mv same same`
- If there are duplicate lines after editing, one of the original files may silently disappear.
- The script may behave unexpectedly in certain corner cases:

  - the user deleted a line from the file
  - the user inserted a line in the file
  - the list of files in the directory changed while editing the file
- The user may not have a way to abort the operation. With default shell settings, even if `nvim` exits with failure, the script goes ahead with the renames, which is probably not what a user would want.
- Even with the double-quoting fixed, the script will not work for files whose names contain newlines. I think that's acceptable and not worth the pain to make it work, but it would be good to document (in a comment).

To mitigate these issues, I suggest:

- Create an array from `*`, let's call it `oldnames`
- Save `oldnames` to the work file: `printf '%s\n' "${oldnames[@]}" > "$work"`
- Let the user edit the work file
- Check the exit code, and abort on failure (user can cause failure by exiting `nvim` with `:cq`)
- Load the content of the work file into another array: `mapfile -t newnames < "$work"`
- Add a sanity check to verify that the number of files match before and after.
- Run `mv` only for the files whose names changed, and use `-i` to avoid overwriting existing files, and `-v` to show what was actually renamed.

#### Use `mktemp` to create temporary files

The script is not safe to use concurrently.
It's easy enough to create a unique temporary file using `mktemp`.

#### Use `trap` to clean up temporary files

To make sure that temporary files get cleaned up when the script exits, use `trap`, for example:

```
trap 'rm -f "$tmpfile"' EXIT
```

Declare this trap right before creating `tmpfile`.

#### Declare all local variables as `local`

It's good you declared `local files`. There is `filenum` too.

#### Don't use `seq`

The `seq` utility is not installed by default in all systems,
and Bash has a native way to use counting loops:

```
for ((i = 0; i < size; i++)); do ...; done
```

#### If you use Bash arrays, reap all the benefits

Instead of `$(ls | wc -l)` to find the count of files,
you already have that in the `files` array: `${#files[@]}`.

#### Improve performance

Calling `sed` in a loop to get the n-th line of a file is inefficient.
It would be better to read the lines into an array,
and then use a counting loop to with the two arrays, for example:

```
for ((i = 0; i < ${#oldnames[@]}; i++)); do
    old=${oldnames[i]}
    new=${newnames[i]}
    if [[ "$old" != "$new" ]]; then
        mv -vi "$old" "$new"
    fi
done
```

Comment: I implemented all of your suggestions. Learned a lot from them. Thank you. [New question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/225058/bulk-file-rename-improved-safety-and-performance).